# java: How to print JForm

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, printing

I am having code of print a string, which is passed in the program itself. Here I am calling this code on Print button to get hard copy. Now I want to print a JForm in the same code, But I am not getting how to do this. JForm having some labels and textfields of user's details. This is the code where I am printing a string"Hello World".

```
public class PrintClass implements Printable, ActionListener {
public int display(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                 PrinterException {
     if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */

   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
   g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now we perform our rendering */

   g.drawString("Hello World", 100, 100);


    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */

   return PAGE_EXISTS;
 }
```

Please help me to call constructor of a JForm, instead of pass the string.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the `Graphics` of your current `JFrame` into a `BufferedImage` and then draw the image into the printer's `Graphics`.

```
Graphics g = myFrame.getContentPane().getGraphics();
// draw graphics into an image
// draw the image into the printer's graphics
```

It is important to note that you should always get a new `Graphics` object from your `JFrame` whenever you want to print the form content

Comment: @user1415022 [rest are in official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)

Comment: @mKorbel thanks for the link, forgot to mention it in the answer :)